# Problems with the EE3 minium stone and the Buildcraft auto-crafting table

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-equivalent-exchange

When I put a minium stone in an auto-crafting table it won't place in. I am using version 1.5.2. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this, or an alternative mod that can auto-craft things. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Automatic Crafting Table requires an adjacent inventory for things like that, so putting a minium stone in a chest next to it and THEN placing into the ACT might work.

Comment: Thanks this explained what i was missing. Sorry about the delay.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with these mods, but my guess would be that maybe if the minium stone is damaged it cannot be placed into the auto crafting table. So, I guess to fix it would be to create a non-damaged minium stone and put it in the auto-crafting table. But, if the stone isn't damaged and you still can't put it in, then I have clue.

Answer (score 1):

Place a chest down next to the autocrafting table.  Put one or more minium stones in the chest,  place an undamaged minium stone into the autocrafting table in your recipe.  When the autocrafting table crafts the recipe one of the stones in the chest will take the damage, and the one in the recipe will remain.